# How to make a request after the variable changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm making a react app and I'm using Auth0 for authentication. I want to make a http request on page refresh but only if `isLoading` variable is equal to false, so I can access user object. So I have to wait until the variable's value changes and than make the request. I tried using useEffect with setTimeout but it doesn't seem to work. Does someone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `setTimeouts`. use the hook `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
  !isLoading && foo(); // your function
}, [isLoading]);
```